Characterization of a coupling based on an ODE solver
Let us assume $ p_0 $ is a probability distribution over $ \mathbb{R}^d $. Let $ x_t $ be a diffusion process defined as:
\begin{equation}
x_t = x + \sigma_t z,
\end{equation}
where $ x \sim p_0 $, $ z \sim \mathit{N}(0,I) $, and $ \sigma_t < \sigma_{t+\varepsilon} $ for any $ \varepsilon > 0 $, with $ \sigma_t \in \mathbb{R}_+ $. Thus, we have $ p(x_t) = p_0 * \mathit{N}(0, \sigma_t^2 I) $, where $ * $ denotes the convolution operator.
Now, assume that we have access to an ODE solver of the diffusion process:
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} = v_t(x),
\end{equation}
with an associated flow function that satisfies:
\begin{equation}
f_t(x_t) = x_t - \int_0^t v_s(x_s) \, ds.
\end{equation}
Next, define the following random variable:
$$\tilde{x_t} = f_t(x + \sigma_t z) + \sigma_t z.$$
What can be said about: (i) the distribution of $ \tilde{x_t} $? (ii) the coupling between $ f_t(x + \sigma_t z) $ and $ z $?
My intuition is that the flow from the ODE solver, $ f_t(x + \sigma_t z) $, enables better alignment (and reduced transport cost) between the pair $ (f_t(x + \sigma_t z), z) $ compared to $ (x, z) $, but I was not able to formalize it.
